# How to resize all elements in Jquery Mobile for fitting inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, jquery-mobile, resize

I am writing an app with jQuery Mobile that will act as a *preview* of a native mobile app, inside a browser.

I am intending to place the webapp in an iframe that will be like a small smartphone simulation. The legibility of the text is *not* important, only the colors, images and the overall look-and-feel.

The problem is that the in our website the preview area is small (`height="330" width="220"`) and everything appears cramped (the text, buttons, etc have normal size but appear big compared to the iframe dimensions).

I tried to apply `font-size: 50%;` or `width: 220px; height: 330px;` in the body of the mobile app but no luck. Also the meta viewport didn't help.

My iframe is something like this:

```
<iframe id="webapp" frameborder="0" height="330" width="220"
  src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/">​
```

I need to make the JQM webapp smaller or "zoomed out", but could not find a good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some stubborn research I found an elegant way to shrink the webapp inside the iframe. By using CSS3 2D transforms:

```
transform:scale(0.5,0.5);
-ms-transform:scale(0.5,0.5); /* IE 9 */
-moz-transform:scale(0.5,0.5); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:scale(0.5,0.5); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform:scale(0.5,0.5); /* Opera */
```

This style will make the iframe 50% smaller.

The downside is that only IE9+ is supported, but this is ok as we all hate IE. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the body { width: 220px; height: 330px; } and the meta-viewport tag? You should actually just make it 320x480 since most screens have that resolution.

Comment: Yes but the result is the same. It is must be 220x330 because it is intended as a preview in our website and not for a mobile screen.